# Angular 7 custom input spinner

Tags: angular, input, numbers, spinner, angular7

I am new to Angular and would like to know the following:
Is there a way to make an input spinner like in the picture? It should automatically count up / down the value of the input field if the button remains pressed and stop when I let it go. As with the normal html input spinner when I set the type property to "number".

I use Angular 7 with material design

Picture:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XETmC6cyGG42k8C4UYTrZnjFEEeOhHKK/view?usp=sharing

My current code for the button and the input field is the following. However, I am open for any changes if necessary:

```
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="count = count + 1">+
              </button>
              </td>
              <td class="center-input">
                <input matInput name="counter" type="text" size="2" min="0" [(ngModel)]="colony.metMine" readonly required>
             </td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="count = count - 1" [disabled]="count < 1">-
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of adding `count=count+1` in the (click) event call a function and pass parameter which says increment or decrement

**yourcomponent.ts**

```
counter(flag){

  if(flag==='increment'){
    this.count++;
  }
  if(flag==='decrement'){
    this.count--;
  }
 this.colony.metMine= this.count;
}
```

**yourcomponenet.html**

```
<table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="counter('increment')">+
          </button>
          </td>
          <td class="center-input">
            <input matInput name="counter" type="text" size="2" min="0" [(ngModel)]="colony.metMine" readonly required>
         </td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="counter('decrement')" [disabled]="count < 1">-
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

So, this is basically updating the same count property of your component class and post each updated it assigns the value of count to colony.metMine variable which is two way binded.

Comment: That is not the solution. It works when i click on it. But if i hold the mousebutton, nothing happens. It doese not count automatically up, as long as i press the mousebutton. I need a Button which doese the same thing as a normal input-field up and down arrow